# How can I make Solr 7.3 recognize a new entry in its schema.xml file?

Tags: solr

I have a recently installed Solr 7.3 server running on an Amazon EC2 instance.  I would like to make use of DateRangeFields as dynamic fields.  I took the following steps:

(1) In server/solr/configsets/my_config/conf/, I moved managed-schema to schema.xml.

(2) In the same location, I added `<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory" />` to solrconfig.xml.

(3) I edited schema.xml and added the following:

```
<dynamicField name="*_rd" type="rdate" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_rds" type="rdates" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

and later:

```
<fieldType name="rdate" class="solr.DateRangeField" docValues="true" />
<fieldType name="rdates" class="solr.DateRangeField" docValues="true" multiValued="true" />
```

(4) In the Solr admin GUI, I found my collection and reloaded it.  I confirmed that it shows the correct configName in the collection overview.

(5) When examining the Dynamic Fields in the admin GUI, I see neither `*_rd` nor `*_rds`.  When examining the Types, I see neither `rdate` nor `rdates`.

[image: No sign of rdates here...]

(6) Hoping that turning it off and turning it on again might produce a different result, I stopped and restarted Solr.  No luck.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Since you're mentioning collections, I assume that you're running Solr in its cloud mode. Any configuration is then stored in the Zookeeper instance, and not in Solr directly. You should also probably use the SchemaAPI when using Solr in Cloud mode, since that'll replicate all changes to all nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @MatsLindh.  I was under the impression the administrative GUI used Schema API to do its work.  Is that incorrect?